# Change colour in ListView

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the colour in a ListView because I want to use a white background. Without touching the ListView it is showing no Text. On touch the background switches to black and the Text is visible because the text is white.
How can I change the Textcolour and avoid that the background changes it's colour when touching?
Here is my code:

```
        public class LayoutNight extends Fragment {

        ListView myList;

        String[] listContent = {

                "Mo", 
                "Di", 
                "Mi",
                "Do",
                "Fr", 
                "Sa", 
                "So"

        };

        public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
            LayoutNight f = new LayoutNight();  

            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_night, null);     

            myList = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter

            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),

                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,

                 listContent);



            myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
// That was a try, but it crashed ...

    //        TextView myListText = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.list);
    //        myListText.setTextColor(color.black);

            return root;
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

I did the suggestions of Raghunandan, but the background not changed.
This is the untouched screenshot

[image: untouched]

This is the the screen at scrolling (***unfortunately black***)
[image: scrolling]

And this is the screen at selecting an option
[image: selecting option]

**EDIT**
It's working now like following without changing the background while scrolling (Thanks to Pragnani and Raghunandan) but it is **not clickable** anymore. How can I make it clickable?

```
    <ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/listbkg"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent">
</ListView>
```

list_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5px"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="75px"/>
```

Code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_night, null);     

    myList = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
    = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_row,listContent);

    myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    myList.setFocusable(true);
    myList.setClickable(true);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    return root;
}
```

Comment: You will have to make your own listview adapter in order to achieve this!

Comment: Instead of this  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, use your custom layout with only one textview and set it as a layout resource to your ArrayAdapter. Give the properties you like i.e textcolor, size etc to it

Comment: But this wont change the changing of the color while touching.
You need a selector for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817776/problem-setting-listview-selector-color-when-pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the theme to *Theme.Light*, sorry I'm a beginner ...

This is now the ListView

```
    <ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@color/white"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent">
</ListView>
```

And following the Code snippset

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_night, null);     

    myList = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
    = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,listContent);

    myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    View header = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);

    myList.addHeaderView(header);        
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a custom adapter. Easy for customization.

In your getview inflate yout custom layout.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html. Check the topic under State list.

```
public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    vh= new ViewHolder();

    if(arg1==null )
        {
        arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, arg2,false);  
        }
    else
    {
     arg1.setTag(vh);
    }

    return arg1;
}
```

customlayout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="@drawable/listbkg" //set layout background
 android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
>
 // other ui elements. similarly you can set background for your other ui elements
 //android:background="@drawable/otherui"
 // define your own drawables when pressed and in normal state. 

</LinearLayout>
```

listbkg.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
```

pressed.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>    
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF"/>
<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

normal.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    //can change color
<stroke android:width="3dp"         //border color  
        android:color="#0FECFF" /><!-- #330000FF #ffffffff -->
<gradient          //add gradient depending on your need else you can remove this
    android:startColor="#ffffffff"  
    android:endColor="#110000FF" 
    android:angle="90"/> 

<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"//for rounded corners
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

I am not sure if its the same color as above. But working principle is the same

[image]

Comment: @user1390816 try the above.

Comment: Unfortunately the Background Color not changed. I attached the screenshots in the edit of my post.

Comment: I haves tested the above. It shouls if you do it the right way.

Comment: ok, then I did an error. Are the colors the same in your app than the screenshots above?

Comment: check the snapshot i attached. The row color changes to green on click and returns back to original color on release. I have not implemented rounded corner and borders.

Comment: But how can I change the text color to black and the background color to white on touching and in normal, any idea? Thanks!

Comment: implement different state list for background and textview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27035/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user1390816)

Comment: In the listbkg.xml file? There is no background and textview: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html or where?